# Guild Wars : Is it possible to finish the Underworld quests with heroes?

Tags: guild-wars

Is it possible to have heroes in your party for the Underworld quests?  If so, how many of your 8 party members is it practical to have be heroes in order to finish the quests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly an extremely difficult challenge, but it is possible to do it with one human player and 7 heroes, and here's a guide on how to do it: http://www.guildwarsguru.com/forum/7h-underworld-guide-t10480563.html

Answer (score 4):

There are a few specific spots where having additional people would greatly help as heros can get overwhelmed quite easily.  Also, having a few very specialized builds would greatly help.  Namely, a obsidian flesh elementalist and a spellbreaker monk.

1. The Four Horsemen - the enemies comes as two split groups here, most teams send 1 obsidian flesh tank + SB monk handle one side while the team takes out the other half.
2. Escort of Souls - It helps a lot if one person triggers the quest while the rest of the party remains at the spawning point to kill enemies and clear the path.  Otherwise, the souls will die.
3. Servants of Grenth - same thing as the Four Horsemen, two groups will spawn, one towards the king one towards the reaper and you must protect both.

There are a few other tips and tricks that a skilled UW quester should know, I haven't done this in a while and the last time I did the mission was with my guild.  It is highly recommended you go in with at least one person who knows what they are doing.  Even a proper UW run with a prepared team will take ~1.5 hours.

Short answer, the more knowledgeable human players you can get, the easier UW will be.  It will be extremely hard to do with just heroes.

Comment: If you have an obby, you're not going to need to split the Monk with him as long as he can dodge a bone spike worth a crap. 4H's Sig of Humility has almost no duration, and Obby is completely maintainable now (and extremely boring to play in UW, as there really isn't enough spell damage down there to kill you anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that you cannot take Heroes into these areas. They will be removed from the team when you enter.
http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Underworld

As for small team builds there are lots for farming the Underworld and Fissure of Woe, or doing chest runs.
Have a look through these, and check out the ones marked (UW) Underworld and (FoW) Fissure of Woe.

Also I would do a search on YouTube for some solo or two man team clears. Be sure to check the dates on the videos though, as some may be old and skills will have changed.

**Edit**

> Henchmen cannot enter this area, but Heroes can.

So yes, it seems that you can build the small team builds using Heroes. As for the completion of the quests, I see no reason why you couldn't build an entire Hero team to tackle these zones.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember - there are some splits strongly recommended for some quests, so its pretty hard to do UW with heroes only.